# Batch file fails on Azure DevOps Command Line task

Tags: windows, azure, batch-file, azure-devops

I am trying to see if there's an active session on the self hosted VMs by using the following script:

```
@echo off
echo Current User: %USERNAME%
echo.

echo Sessions Active ------------
query user %USERNAME%
echo.

for /f "skip=1 tokens=4" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do ( 
    set status=%%s
    echo Status: %status%
    if not "%status%"=="Active" goto error
    color A
    echo Session Active!
    goto end
)

:error
color C
echo Warning!!! Session not active as expected!
exit /b 1

:end
color 7
exit /b 0
```

The script when run locally on both administrator & non-administrator windows prints the following:

```
c:\C#>session 
Current User: Administrator

Sessions Active ------------  
USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>administrator         console             1  Active      none   4/26/2021 9:05 PM

Status: Active Session Active!
```

However, when I run the same using cmd /c $(Build.SourcesDirectory\SessionTest.bat from the Azure DevOps pipeline, I get the following output:

```
Starting: Are Agents Active?
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.182.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
cmd /c "C:\agent\_work\2\s\SessionTest.bat"
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\agent\_work\_temp\058a0887-9ca1-4620-8ff7-220151fdf56f.cmd""
Current User: ehpadmin

Sessions Active ------------
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>ehpadmin              console             1  Active      none   5/11/2021 8:08 PM

Status: 
Warning!!! Session not active as expected!
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Are Agents Active?
```

Apparently, the below statements are not getting the STATE and assigning the variable propertly.  What am I doing wrong?

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=4" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do ( 
    set status=%%s
    echo Status: %status%
```

Comment: There is no way the batch file works correctly in either environment because you are not using delayed expansion.

Comment: to avoid `delayedepansion` why not just skip the `set` all together? `for /f "skip=1 tokens=4" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do echo Status: %%~s`

Answer (score 1):

Just skip the `parenthesized block all together and use the metavariables that the` for` loop already defined:

```
@echo off
echo Current User: %USERNAME%
echo(

echo Sessions Active ------------
query user %USERNAME%
echo(

for /f "skip=1 tokens=4" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do if /i not "%%~s" == "Active" goto :error
Color A & echo session Active & timeout /t 2 >nul
goto :end

:error
color C
echo Warning!!! Session not active as expected!
exit /b 1

:end
color 7
exit /b 0
```

and If you are using Windows 10, we can make it fancier by using escape codes:

```
@echo off
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $E ^| cmd') do set "cl=%%a"

cls & echo Current User: %cl%[35m%USERNAME%%cl%[0m
echo(
for /f "skip=1 tokens=4" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do if /i not "%%~s" == "Active" (
    echo %cl%[31mWarning!!! Session not active as expected!%cl%[0m
    exit /b && goto :eof
)
echo %cl%[92mSession Active%cl%[0m
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort.  I'm lazy so I just modified couple of things like indicated by @squashman's link. :D

Comment: Nothing much to do here, you copy the code as is, you paste it.

Comment: Of course!  I appreciated the assist.  You gave me the fish .  But I also wanted to understand the reason why it didn’t work.  You alluded to it by asking me to remove the block . Thank you!

Comment: @Gerard:  I took your awesome code in its entirety once I had a chance to understand it and run it.  Very concise.  Thank you.

Comment: Cool, glad you find it helpful.